# Como transformar URL em domínio

Tags: php, servidor

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP 7, que funciona da seguinte forma:

Exemplo

```
http://www.myapp.com.br/username
```

Cada cliente tem um *username* para configurar e editar as suas informações. Quando se entra com essa url, faço a tratativa no banco e busco informações de acordo com o *username* da url que é único.

Queria que cada cliente pudesse ter um domínio próprio seu, que apontasse para meu site e virasse um domínio.

Exemplo:

```
http://www.myapp.com.br/empresaxyz -> www.empresaxyz.com.br
```

Dando uma lida, achei sobre CNAME, mais pelo que entendi ele funciona apenas para subdomínios, sendo que minha aplicação não funciona assim.

Como posso reutilizar minha aplicação para um domínio do cliente?

Comment: Para cadastrar domínios `.com.br` você deve entrar em contato com o [registro.br](https://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-hospedagem.html).

Comment: Sim, já estou ciente dessa parte, de fazer alteração no registro.br. Mas qual parte tenho que alterar, pois pelo que li, o CNAME só funciona em subdomínios e domínios.

Comment: Eles estão falando de subdomínios, não precisa, pelo que eu entendi você vai precisar agrupar esses clientes em uma categoria do banco e determinar para cada um deles uma página do perfil. Sem o código fica complexo ajudar. O Wordpress faz algo similar com post's na configuração de URL.